# create column data mysql evaluating hour column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a column datatime type hour in mysql, and I want read this column and create other with days for each hour(0-23:59). I put an image for explain better. I will intent with

```
for rowshour
  day = 0
  if rowhour[i] < rowhour
     day = day + 1
```

Thanks for all. Best regards!

The table, and the column of date same i want
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87tEN.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are just asking for 2 columns.

```
|--id--|--name--|----dt----|--hr--|
|  1   |  Data  |2015-04-22|  00  |
|  1   |  Data  |2015-04-22|  12  |
|  1   |  Data  |2015-04-22|  20  |
|  1   |  Data  |2015-04-22|  21  |
```

For hour (hr) I would use an integer instead of a datetime. For dt I would use the datetime, so you have the exact minute. Then when you query use date(),

Finally you can always use the ever incrementing integer format of this:
YYYYMMDDHH, for example 2015-04-22 at 12 would be 2015042212

Comment: I have these table in 2 columns, hour (varchar)and name(varchar) from csv. I convert the column hour in datatime type for filter and show of hours. I will agreggate the date for show only day hours, I think use a integer in date for use a loop for read the column of hours and divide for days, but I will intent your solution. Thanks for all. Regards

Comment: Your CSV has no dates?  If it does, then `GROUP BY DATE(date)`

Comment: Not, the csv have "hour:minutes","data" :S its the problem the rows order by id(column create for me)